# keras model.predict says incorrect input shape but it seems the same

Tags: python, keras

I have a model that I'm making predictions on using keras. But keras is giving me incorrect shape error.

```
expected dense_1_input to have shape (13,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Here's the code:

```
model.summary()
print(seq)
print(seq.shape)
location_onehot = model.predict(seq)
```

Output:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 28
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 6
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 6
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 6
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 320)               960
=================================================================
Total params: 1,006
Trainable params: 1,006
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
[ 1  5  6  2  2  3 20  3  3  3  1  1  1]
(13,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "infer.py", line 78, in <module>
    dompath_loc_infer_all()
  File "infer.py", line 11, in dompath_loc_infer_all
    print('location:', predict_loc(i), '\n')
  File "/mnt/c/Users/psharma/Desktop/TADigital/dom/decode.py", line 13, in predict_loc
    location_onehot = model.predict(seq)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1149, in predict
    x, _, _ = self._standardize_user_data(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 751, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 138, in standardize_input_data
    str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (13,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Comment: Did you try `model.predict([seq])`?

Comment: Yes I did. Same error.

Comment: Can you provide what is the expected model input? Like the output shape of `dense_1` is `(batch_size, 2)`. But what is the expected input shape? Is it `(batch_size, 13)` ?

Comment: Yes, the input shape for the first layer should be (13, 1)

Comment: Wait, so total number of features are `13`, yes?

Comment: yeah that's right

Comment: Input shape should be `(None, 13)`. Not `(13, 1)`.

Comment: I figured it out. I did
```

wrapper = []
wrapper.append(seq)
seq = np.asarray(wrapper)

```